# Discord.js time related events

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make the bot writing messages at specific times. Example:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Online!");
});
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getUTCHours();
var minute = now.getUTCMinutes();
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (hour === 10 && minute === 30) {
        client.channels.get("ChannelID").send("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

unfortunately it only works once i trigger another command like:

```
if (message.content.startsWith("!ping")) {
    message.channel.send("pong!");
}
-> pong
-> Hello World!
```

so it doesn't work automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use setInterval().

```
function sendsomeMessage() {
client.channels.get("id here").send("Hello world!")
}
setInterval(sendsomeMessage, time in miliseconds here)
```

Remember to place this in the `client.on("message", (message) => {` event

Comment: well, now it is just constantly spamming once the "if" has been triggered